SQL Script that will adjust the value of the next row when it finds a negative
Is there a plain SQL script that will adjust the value from a table when it finds a negative until it consumes the negative values?
like for example>
0
,1952
,0
,0
,0
,0
,0
,98
,-333
,98
,98
,98
,165
,113
,113
,113
,138
,65
,65
,115

there is a -333 in the list so the result will be like this
0
,1952
,0
,0
,0
,0
,0
,98
,-333
,-235
,-137
,-39
,126
,113
,113
,113
,138
,65
,65
115

as you can see 165 is now 126, since it consumes the negative value, all the next value remain as-is
Thanks in advance.

What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Yes, there's a way, but it's a bit messy. Are you sure you want to do this? What kind of data are you working with that needs this weird logic

I've tried to union it on the table and issue the sum(partition by) but it will just sum the rows and it will not adjust the next rows. :(

I'm working on a analytics report, I'm transforming the formula from excel as requested by the user. but yeah, got stuck into this. :(

I also tried to create cte table, then table after tables , but it's getting way too long but no destination..:(

Post something realistic. Databases don't have comma-separated values. You can perform calculations using windowing functions based on actual columns and specific orders. Table rows have no implicit order so if you want to use the "previous" value you have to specify the order in the query

This sounds like a problem that would be easier to fix using a "real" programming language, and very difficult to get right using SQL. If you don't find an SQL-based solution, maybe you could explore adding a custom assembly to your SQL Server to handle that logic.

@LarsKristensen not necessarily -you can easily use LAG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY Date) to get the previous price in a category by date. The query could even take advantage of indexing if written properly. There are are a lot of similar windowing functions that are hard to replicate in procedural languages

also tried that LAG statement,

@JosephKyleDielMahasol analytics report ... formula from excel what's the actual report and fields? What does the formula actually do? There are a lot of aggregate and window functions that can be used. Perhaps you need LAG, perhaps you need SUM() OVER or sum the differences. We can't guess

also tried and? What worked? What didn't? We can't guess what you tried or what failed. Right now we don't even understand what you want. There's nothing wrong with LAG

it does not work. since you need to adjust the next value based on the result of the last processed values and lag only gets the base previous values, not the processed value.

it does not work contains no information. consumes the negative values? that sounds like you want to find the running total of values in the range of values starting with a negative value until the running total reaches 0 or above. That has nothing to do with previous values and therefore LAG. These are two different problems. The running total is easy - SUM(value) OVER(ORDER BY SomeField). To get the running total or the raw value you can use IIF or CASE WHEN. The hard part is finding the range.

Edit the question and explain what you want to do. Add enough information (preferably including CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements) so people can test solutions without guessing. How does the Excel formula find the ranges now? The same logic could be used to create a RangeID that can then be used in SUM. The solution will require subqueries or CTEs so one OVER clause can calculate the ranges generated by a previous one

Assuming you have some kind of sort column, you can use a recursive CTE to calculate the values:
WITH data AS (
SELECT  *
FROM
    (
    VALUES  (0, 1)
    ,   (1952, 2)
    ,   (0, 3)
    ,   (0, 4)
    ,   (0, 5)
    ,   (0, 6)
    ,   (0, 7)
    ,   (98, 8)
    ,   (-333, 9)
    ,   (98, 10)
    ,   (98, 11)
    ,   (98, 12)
    ,   (165, 13)
    ,   (113, 14)
    ,   (113, 15)
    ,   (113, 16)
    ,   (138, 17)
    ,   (65, 18)
    ,   (65, 19)
    ,   (115, 20)
) t (value,sort)
)
, agg AS (
    SELECT  value, sort, CASE WHEN value > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag, value AS agg_value
    FROM    data
    WHERE   sort = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  d.value, d.sort,CASE WHEN value_new > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
    ,   value_new
    FROM    agg a
    INNER JOIN data d
        ON  d.sort = a.sort + 1
    CROSS apply (
        SELECT  CASE WHEN agg_value < 0 THEN a.agg_value + d.value ELSE d.value END AS value_new
        ) f
    )
SELECT  sort, value as orig, agg_value as new
FROM    agg

To keep track of things, i create a flag that changes depending if value is negative or positive, and then apply the strange logic you're using by adding the values until they pass 0.
The output becomes:



sort
orig
new




1
0
0


2
1952
1952


3
0
0


4
0
0


5
0
0


6
0
0


7
0
0


8
98
98


9
-333
-333


10
98
-235


11
98
-137


12
98
-39


13
165
126


14
113
113


15
113
113


16
113
113


17
138
138


18
65
65


19
65
65


20
115
115




This works like a charm ,is date values can be used as the sorting?

I don't see why not :) but you need to change sort into ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by <your date column>) as sort

encountered a problem sir when the negative values are not fully consumed and it counters another negative value again. Sample Query link
fiddle
TestQuery

I edited a new version, does it work better? @JosephKyleDielMahasol

wow...yeah...it works, I guess, this will be the final query. thanks a lot man.....yeahhhh

Great, you can probably fix the @Thom's query as well

I've asked another question on this, just to make sure, since this is not included in the first problem. can you post your answer here ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78505415/adjust-sql-values-when-it-finds-a-negative

@siggerman, is there a way that i can put filter in the cross-join part? cause currently dealing w/ a lot of records

Probably, but i'm not gonna write everything for you :) You have to figure out some things yourself. But i think the other answer is more performant, so if performance is an issue, you should check it out

yeah2x....that's what I'm dealing right now, but many thanks man

The OP likely needs a recursive solution now, @siggemannen . So my solution can't be "fixed"; it solved the problem the OP provided us, but just not their undisclosed new one.

An alternative method, that doesn't require recursion, would be to use a gaps and islands approach. First put your data into groups, depending on how many negative numbers appeared in the data prior. Then you can have make a cumulative SUM for the values in those groups. Finally, you only display the cumulative SUM's value if the prior sum came to a value less than 0, if it didn't just return the value.
WITH Grps AS (
    SELECT YT.YourID,
           YT.YourValue,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN YT.YourValue < 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY YT.YourID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Grp
    FROM YourTable YT),
Sums AS(
    SELECT G.YourID,
           G.YourValue,
           G.Grp,
           SUM(G.YourValue) OVER (PARTITION BY G.Grp ORDER BY G.YourID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeSum
    FROM Grps G)
SELECT S.YourID,
       CASE WHEN LAG(S.CumulativeSum,1,S.CumulativeSum) OVER (PARTITION BY S.Grp ORDER BY S.YourID) < 0 THEN S.CumulativeSum ELSE S.YourValue END AS NewValue
FROM Sums S
ORDER BY S.YourID;

db<>fiddle
Like siggemannen's solution, this required you to have a column to order by (an ID). If you don't have that, your goal is impossible.

That's clever, i didn't think gaps would be applicable here

encountered a problem sir when the negative values are not fully consumed and it counters another negative value again.

fiddle

please see starting row# 33 sir, supposedly row# 34 should add the remaining negative values.

And why was that scenario on in your question, @JosephKyleDielMahasol ? The above won't handle that, as it wasn't part of the problem you described. Also, I'm not knighted, please don't call me "sir".

my bad @ThomA, I just encountered it today, doing testing on the query.
